# SSLException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch

Tags: android, android-studio

I am in learning stage of Android Studio. I was leaning Android Studio few months back, but for some reasons I deleted it... Now I am trying to install Android Studio again in the same device, but the "Tag Mismatch" error is showing in it.

[Image of Dialog Box for Tag Mismatch error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EDBX.png)

I tried everything to fix it:

- Reinstalling Android Studio (after deleting all files that already exists)
- Disable Firewall
- Reset Network
- Disabled the Metered Connection

[Image of Metered Connection setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25Zgu.png)

And in my PC that force `https://` to `http://` setting is also not showing

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8H1d4.png)

I followed all solutions present on internet but the error of Tag Mismatch is not fixed

Please help...

I want a solution for my problem